# MrChrister stepping down from mod duties

Tags: discussion

---

Just a quick note that I am stepping down from my moderation duties.  I will no longer have a diamond by my name, but I will still be reading the site and participating when I can.  Even after 5 years, I still spend more time learning than I do teaching on this site, which is pretty rad.

Thanks to everybody for making a fun and easy group to moderate.  Everybody who comes to the community has a kind heart (except for those bum spammers...) and is obviously interested in helping other people the best they can.

Big thanks to JoeTaxpayer and JohnFx, who are really fun people to work with, and I won't forget the team who taught me how to mod including the site's founder, Chris Rea.

Perhaps some of your have noticed that my job and family life are getting more of my time as times moves on, so I wanted to get out of the way and let another one of our very capable and calm community members the opportunity to work with the StackExchange people and mod the site for while.

*And if you have considered running in the next election, please do so.  I can't imagine a real world job you have that wouldn't benefit from some of the things they teach you as a mod.  (All you programmers especially, you will see how software and real life come together in a world class way.)  The community team at StackExchange are very friendly and will offer as much (or as little) guidance as you want.  It is a super experience.  If you have the means, I highly recommend picking it up.*

Comment: Sad to see you step down. You are a really good moderator. On the bright side, now we can talk about you with impunity int he vault. Muhahaha!

Comment: Thanks for your service MrChrister! Much appreciated. See you 'round.

Comment: @JohnFx and Re: *"now we can talk about you..."* Aha! I just *knew* it! ;)

Comment: I presume that upvotes on this "question" should be taken as expressions of approval of @MrChrister's service, rather than pleasure at his leaving - mine certainly is :-)

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam - ? I was about to downvote to say that I was sorry to see Chris go. But you're correct. It's a show of thanks.